# Super basic hash table set-up memory allocation errors

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

Yes I am still learning C++ and I am trying to create my own Hash.h header with several hash functions (non-cryptic) such as MurmurHash and CityHash. To start this off I just wanted a very basic implementation first. But it is not compiling as I have some memory errors. It is due to adding a entry where data is passed to the class function. Changing to pointers/references gave similar errors and I just can't seem to fix it. Can somebody see what is going wrong such that I know what to look for in the future? Thanks!

```
//Hash.h
template<class T>
class HashEntry{
    private:
        int key;
        T data;
    public:
        HashEntry() {};
        void putData(T input, int keyVal){
            //SEGMENTATION FAULT HAPPENS HERE!!
            key = keyVal;
            data = input;
        }
        T getData(){
            return data;
        }
};

template<class T>
class Hash{
    private:
        int myFunc;
        size_t sizeHash;
        HashEntry<T> **table;
    public:
        Hash(int func, size_t size): myFunc(func), sizeHash(size-1) {
            table = new HashEntry<T>*[sizeHash];
            for (int i=0;i<sizeHash;i++) table[i] = NULL;
        }
        int hashFunc(int key){
            try{
                if (myFunc == 0){
                    return key % sizeHash;
                } else if (myFunc == 1){
                    //other has func's
                } else {string excep = "No such hash function!"; throw excep;}
            } catch(string e) {cout << "Hash::hashFunc(): Exception Raised: " << e << endl; exit(0);}
            return -1;
        }
        void addEntry(T data, int key){
            int myHash = hashFunc(key);
            table[myHash]->putData(data, key);
        }
};
```

Call from main:

```
Hash<char> *myHash = new Hash<char>(0,10);
myHash->addEntry('s', 11);
return 0;
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Is this the complete code you have pasted here that you are trying to compile?

Comment: Also, do you have problem compiling the code or with memory allocation? Your question and title seem contradicting each other.

Comment: I see your code set `table[i]` to `NULL`, and I see it call a member function through `table[myHash]` pointer. But I don't see you ever assign a non-`NULL` value to an pointer stored in `table` array. Where and how do you create instances of `HashEntry<T>`?

Comment: It seems you have filled you rable with null pointers and when adding an object you try to operate on the null pointer rather than creating a new `HashEntry<T>`.

Comment: Stupid mistake! Thanks. Very helpful.